# How to expand nth power of a polynomial.

Tags: polynomials, power-series, formal-power-series

Is there any general way to write down the expansion of $n^{th}$ power of  a polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^s c_ix^i$, i.e., $(\sum_{i=0}^s c_ix^i)^n$ for some positive integer $n$. I know it for only two terms and by induction i can do the same. But is there any other method or explicit formula known?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One could write down a somewhat-explicit formula via the multinomial theorem; it might look something like
$$
   \sum_{k_0  + \dots + k_s = n} \frac{n!}{k_0!\,k_1!\dotsb k_s!}c_0^{k_0} c_1^{k_1} \dotsb c_s^{k_s} x^{k_1 + 2k_2 + \dots + s k_s}
$$
where the sum is over all nonnegative integers $k_0, k_1, \dots, k_s$ that add up to $n$.

This is only a partial solution because there are too many terms: there are $\binom{n+s}{s}$ ways to choose $k_0, \dots, k_s$, but there are actually only $ns + 1$ different powers of $x$ that occur in the final answer.

Unfortunately, a better formula is out of the question. Even the next simplest case after the binomial theorem, expanding $(1 + x + x^2)^n$, does not have a nice closed form: see [sequence A027907 in the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A027907).

Answer (score 6):

A standard way
(i.e., nothing original here)
 to generate the coefficients
for
$f(x)
=g^n(x)
$
where
$g(x)
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_kx^k
$
is this:

$f'(x)
=ng'(x)g^{n-1}(x)
$
so
$f'(x)g(x)
=ng'(x)g^{n}(x)
=ng'(x)f(x)
$.

Writing
$f(x)
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_kx^k
$,
$f'(x)
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kb_kx^{k-1}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)b_{k-1}x^{k}
$
and
$g'(x)
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)a_{k-1}x^{k}
$.

Equating coefficients in
$f'(x)g(x)
=ng'(x)f(x)
$,
we get a recurrence for
the $b_k$.

Note that $n$
does not have to be an integer.

This takes about
$k$ operations to generate
each $b_k$,
so about
$k^2$ operations
for the first $k$ $b_k$s.

If $g$ is a polynomial,
either stop at the non-zero coefficients
or set the higher order terms to zero.

For more of this, see
generatingfunctionology:

https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html

This is a free download and an invaluable resource.

Answer (score 1):

As in the two term case with the binomial theorem, the $m$ term to the $n$th power case is the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem), with the multinomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k_1! k_2! \cdots k_m!}$.