# Is there any extension of Newton's Binomial Theorem for general Polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

What I'm asking is: We have that
$$
(x+y)^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n} {n \choose i} x^{n-i}y^i.
$$
Is there any formula for $f^m$, where $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^n$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: Thanks man, I wasn't searching it with the right terms. If you answer with the result and the link I will gladly accept it (the result is necessary because the bots don't accept just the link as a valid answer).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2652580/how-to-expand-nth-power-of-a-polynomial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with the [Multinomial Theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Multinomial_theorem), which shows how to expand a power of a multinomial in an arbitrary number of variables in terms of monomials:
$$
(u_0 + \cdots + u_n)^m = \sum_{k_0 + \cdots + k_n = m} 
\binom{n}{k_0 \, \cdots \, k_n} 
u_0^{k_0} \cdots u_n^{k_n},
$$
where the multinomial coefficient is given by
$$
\binom{m}{k_0 \, \cdots \, k_n} = \frac{m!}{k_0! \cdots k_n!}. 
$$
Then you would evaluate at
$$
\begin{align*}
u_0 &= a_0 \\
u_1 &= a_1x \\
& \;\;\vdots \\
u_n &= a_nx^n
\end{align*}
$$
and collect like terms. There are recurrence formulas for the coefficients, but I don't believe there are closed forms.

Comment: I think this can be rewritten as $\sum\cdots\sum$ analogously to the binomial form, this could be tricky though.